# OSX Yosemite My Calendar Icon Stopped Updating

Tags: macos, calendar, dock

Since upgrading to Yosemite, the calendar icon in my dock has been stuck on October 17. I have had no luck getting it to display the correct date.

Has anyone else run into/found a solution for this issue? Its driving me insane.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old, but for those still looking for a quick fix:

Open up the terminal and enter the following command:
`'killall Dock'`

This should reload your dock, including all of the icons thus updating the date displayed in the calendar icon.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the computer and unchecked the "reopen all windows" checkbox, and the issue was resolved when I logged in.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only a temporary solution, I have found that the issue comes back a few days later, and can, again, only be fixed with a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Seems calendar needs to be open to update icon on dock.

Comment: This is not the case for me, I never quit the calendar app and still have the issue.